# Why we need to use layout panels in GWT when we are already having CSS for layouting?

Tags: css, gwt, layoutpanels

Why we need to use layout panels in GWT when we are already having CSS for layouting?

e.g in gwt we use layoutpanel to layout StackLayoutPanel

```
layoutpanel.setWidgetLeftWidth(stackpanel, 5, Unit.PCT, 30, Unit.EM);
```

Comment: What are you asking? “Why GWT has widgets for layouts where there's already CSS for that?” or “Why you need to use layout panels when you're already using CSS for layouts?”

Comment: @thomas: Why GWT has widgets for layouts where there's already CSS for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three reasons:

A. Faster programing.

B. Cleaner code.

GWT panels support much more functionality than a div with an absolute/relative positioning. You don't have to use panels: you can use HTML and CSS in a Ui:Binder, but then you will have to do certain things manually. Basically, you will have to program at close to jQuery level.

GWT panels can be extended, which you cannot do with a div.

C. Browser compatibility.

GWT was developed when browsers were much less compatible with each other. It is slowly becoming less of an issue, but differences still exist, and GWT supports even older browsers that are still being widely used.